# Convert Facebook API datetime to Sql datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, facebook-graph-api, datetime

From Facebook API, I get the date in the following format

> 2014-04-06T00:08:29+0000

I want to insert this into datetime field in SQL Server. I tried

```
select convert(datetime,convert(varchar(50),'2014-04-06T00:08:29+0000',126),126)
```

and

```
select convert(datetime,'2014-04-06T00:08:29+0000',126)
```

but both gave me conversion failed errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use style 127 (with timezone), like this:

```
select convert(datetime,'2014-04-06T00:08:29+0000',127)
```

(however, this will work only is the timezone in +/- HH:MM format:

```
2014-04-06T00:08:29+00:00
```

In your case you can use style 126, but you need to truncate the string to 19 characters, like this:

```
select convert(datetime,SUBSTRING('2014-04-06T00:08:29+0000', 1, 19),126)
```

Comment: That din't help mate, running the above query still gives conversion failed error

Comment: Yeah, I see that after removing the last 5 characters, the query works. However, ain't there any format which will convert it directly without editing?

Comment: The list of styles for CONVERT function is displayed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx. Facebook API style is not in the list

Comment: yeah mate, I had seen that link and din't found so asked here. anyways thanks, I guess, I will have to proceed using substring.